# Reply to sender via email with SendGrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-api-v2

I have a use-case where user A can send user B a message from our website, which I am using SendGrid to send the message in an email. Then user B can reply to the email with their message and I would like that message to be received at user A’s email. I have been able to setup sending the email from user A to user B with no problems, but I can’t see in the documentation how to configure the email from user B back to user A. Additionally, if there is a conversation back and forth between both users then I would like to keep that in the email thread. Surely this is possible with SendGrid?

Comment: Did you try using the header fields such as Message ID or unique arguments for this? https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/unique-arguments

Answer (score 2):

I have been using replyTo like this:

```
const message = {
  to: 'someemail@email.com',
  replyTo: 'test@test.com'
  bcc: ['test@test.com'],
  from: 'test@test.com',
  text: 'email',
  html: '<strong>email</strong>',      
  substitutions: {
    // key-values pairs for substitutions
  }
}
```

Comment: kindly explain more